# Indesign Automation

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, xml

We are planning to automate in-design flow

1. Create a base design with place holders
2. Tag all the placeholders
3. Export the content as xml/ export as Idml
4. Update xml/idml (html form to update conent)
5. Import back to original design

Is this flow works ?, which will be better option (export as xml or idml).

Editing xml will easy but it breaks design mostly .
Idml edit is difficult

Please suggest any idea to overcome this problem

thanks..